# Is it possible to have an "or" to initialize a variable with 2 strings in Python?

Tags: python, variables, initialization

Is it possible to have an "or" to initialize a variable with 2 strings?
This is the variable:
correctAnswer = "Black" or "black"

Here is my code; it runs for "Black" but it does not recognize the "black":

```
x = 1
correctAnswer = "Black" or "black"

colorAnswer = input("Guess my favorite color: ")
while colorAnswer != correctAnswer:
  print("Sorry, but that is not my favorite color.  Please try again.")
  colorAnswer = input("Guess my favorite color: ") 
  x = x + 1
print("That is correct, my favorite color is Black.  It only took you " + str(x) + " 
tries.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a set with `correctAnswer = {'Black', 'black'}` and check with `if colorAnswer in correctAnswer:`.

It might be even better to use an other approach and convert the input to lowercase before checking. Then you would have `correctAnswer = 'black'` and `if colorAnswer.lower() = correctAnswer:`.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can't initialize a variable like that. You could check the condition directly:

```
while color not in ('black', 'Black'):
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Another possibility is to randomize the initialization of your color.

```py
import random

color = random.choice(["red", "black"])
```